# Setting Position of NSWindow before Display

Tags: cocoa

Right now I'm setting the position of a window that is about to open like this:

```
-(void) setActiveNodeDialog:(ISKNodeDialogController *)dialog
{
    if (activeNodeDialog)
        [[activeNodeDialog window] close];
    activeNodeDialog = dialog;
    if (activeNodeDialog) {
        [activeNodeDialog setMainWindowController:self];
        NSRect windowRect = [[self window] frame];
        NSRect dialogRect = [[activeNodeDialog window] frame];
        NSPoint pos;
        pos.x = windowRect.origin.x + windowRect.size.width - dialogRect.size.width - 10;
        pos.y = windowRect.origin.y + 32;
        [[activeNodeDialog window] setFrameOrigin:pos];
        [[activeNodeDialog window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem with that is, that the window will "jump" when shown.  And that even though I set the position before showing the window with "makeKeyAndOrderFront".  The window is a `NSPanel *`.  Anyone any ideas how to fix the jumping?

Setting the position in awakeFromNib is not an option because the main controller is set later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Interface Builder, is "visible at launch" checked for the window? If so uncheck it and then you won't even need this code [[activeNodeDialog window] close];. Basically if that is checked then the window is automatically shown when the xib is instantiated... which you don't want.

Comment: Indeed, that was causing that problem. Thanks